# How i can get value from database

Tags: reactjs, firebase

i need to get online status of user 
here's function where i listen online status

```
onlineStatus(id) {
        app.database().ref('users').child(id).child('connections').on('value', (snapshot) => {
            return snapshot.val();
        })
    }
```

but when i try to use this function in return function i get undefined value

```
{this.state.diologs.map(i =>
                            this.state.searchResult.length === 0 && this.state.isDiologOpen === false &&

                            <div className="resultField" >

                                <img src="/images/noavatar.png" id="userImage" />
                                <p className="userName">{i.name} {i.surname}  </p>
                                <p>{i.lastMessage}</p>

                                <button onClick={() => this.writeMessage(i)}>Написать сообщение</button>
                                {this.onlineStatus(i.id) ? <p>Online</p> : <p>Offline</p>}
```

the problem is in this line

```
{this.onlineStatus(i.id) ? <p>Online</p> : <p>Offline</p>}
```

Comment: Use `once()` instead of `on()` to query a single time and return a promise to the caller with the data from the query.

Comment: It shows undefined because `onlineStatus` doesn't return any data. The return statement inside `onlineStatus` currently just return for the callback instead of the method. I don't have enough information about the context of your problem but seems like your approach is not effective and even not doable. React rendering doesn't work that way.